# Como acessar site em rede local digitando o endereço virtual (vhost)?

Tags: apache, xampp

Fala pessoal. Tudo bem?
Vamos lá! Há bastante tempo eu uso o Xampp para desenvolver, hospedar e acessar localmente meus sites. Na pasta *htdocs* crio meus diretórios, como de padrão (**meusite1**, **meusite2**, **meusite3** e assim por diante). Daí através dos arquivos *hosts* e *vhosts* configuro para acessar cada site digitando **meusite1.loc**, **meusite2.loc** e assim por diante. Porém isso só funciona se eu estiver no PC onde o Xampp está instalado.
Para acessar a partir de outros dispositivos na mesma rede, preciso digitar o ip ou nome da máquina, seguido do nome da pasta (site) que eu pretendo acessar (**192.168.xx.9/meusite2**).
Então, como eu faço pra acessar cada site a partir de outro dispositivo apenas digitando o endereço configurado no meu vhosts (**meusite1.loc**)?

Comment: você vai ter de criar um alias pro IP da sua máquina (onde o xamp está instalado), normalmente no arquivo hosts, colocando algo como: `seu.endereco.de.ip meusite1.loc`. Assim na maquina cliente,ao acessar esse endereço vai apontar para a maquina servidor, e lá o xampp se vira.

Comment: Você precisa instalar um serviço de DNS na rede e configurá-lo para apontar seus domínios de teste para o servidor em questão.

Comment: Ou então mexer no HOSTS de todos os PCs. Como disse o @bfavaretto, a solução é um DNS. Pode usar um externo (o mesmo do seu site, mas criando um intranet.nomedosite.com.br apontando pro IP interno - só vai funcionar pra quem estiver na rede certa) ou simplesmente usar o DNS já existente na maioria dos roteadores de rede (ou servidor da empresa, se existir).

Comment: Se não fosse o fato de ter vários, bastaria usar o nome de rede do PC, Como são virtuais, o DNS é necessário (ou vai ter que usar uma gambiarra para diferenciar cada um, como um "seletor" via cookie ou outro mecanismo, mas aí tem que mexer na aplicação, e pode ser longe do ideal).